# Combined ast.literal_eval with sys.argv

Tags: python, linux, eval, sys

I have a python file (lest called `pythonFile.py`) with several definitions, so I want that all definitions can be used both the python interpreter using the file as a module and the linux terminal. E.g:

```
def funct_1(arg1): #if arg1 is a string
    return arg1

def funct_2(arg1, arg2): #if both arg1 and arg2 are integers
    return arg1+arg2

def funct_3(arg1, arg2, arg3): #arg1 is str, arg2 is list, and arg3 is dict
    if (arg1 is str) and (arg2 is list) and (arg3 is dict):
        return 'It is Ok'
    else:
        return 'It is bad, very bad'
```

Therefore, using this script in the interactive interpreter works fine:

```
>>> import pythonFile
>>> func_1('string here')
string here
>>> funct_2(2,4)
6
>>> funct_3(strVar, listVar, dictVar)
It is Ok
```

And to use it in a terminal, I added the following code (with the appropriated modules imported):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print eval(sys.argv[1])(*sys.argv[2:])
```

So, `eval(sys.argv[1])` tells what function I will use, and `(*sys.argv[2:])` indicates which and how many arguments I putting.

This works well for `funct_1`, which only requests a string:

```
$ python filePython.py funct_1 'print me'
print me
```

but not for `funct_2` and `fuct_3`:

```
$ python filePython.py func_2 6 4`
64
$ python filePython.py func_2 strVar listVar dictVar`
It is bad, very bad
```

Obviously, this is due that every argument passed into the terminal is parsed as `string`. One solution is to used `eval()` into the definition. But `eval()` is "evil", so I prefer to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast) which is safer.

```
import sys
from ast import literal_eval as aeval 

def funct_1(arg1): #if arg1 is a string
    return arg1

def funct_2(arg1, arg2): #if both arg1 and arg2 are integers
    return int(arg1)+int(arg2)

def funct_3(arg1, arg2, arg3): #arg1 is str, arg2 is list, and arg3 is dict
    if (arg1 is str) and (aveal(arg2) is list) and (aeval(arg3) is dict):
        return 'It is Ok'
    else:
        return 'It is bad, very bad'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print eval(sys.argv[1])(*sys.argv[2:]) # here I still using eval() instead aeval()
```

Note that in `funct_2` I can use `int()` or `float()` instead any type of `eval()` to solve the problem.
Now, I can use the `funct_3` from the terminal:

```
$ python filePython.py funct_3 strVar listVar dictVar
$ It is Ok
```

But not from the python interpreter:

```
>>> import pythonFile
>>> funct_3(strVar, listVar, dictVar)
It is bad, very bad
```

This is due that `aeval()` now is evaluating `list` and `dict` instead `string`. So, again, I change my code adding a new definition which turn any `dict` and `list` into a `str` to be later evaluated by `aeval()` (yes, I know. This is ugly and stupid, but is the only way that I know so far).

```
import sys
from ast import literal_eval as aeval

def strEval(var):
    return aeval(str(var))

def funct_1(arg1): #if arg1 is a string
    return arg1

def funct_2(arg1, arg2): #if both arg1 and arg2 are integers
    return int(arg1)+int(arg2)

def funct_3(arg1, arg2, arg3): #arg1 is str, arg2 is list, and arg3 is dict
    if (arg1 is str) and (strEval(arg2) is list) and (strEval(arg3) is dict):
        return 'It is Ok'
    else:
        return 'It is bad, very bad'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print eval(sys.argv[1])(*sys.argv[2:])
```

Now, all definitions works well for both python interpreter (as module) and the linux terminal (great!). But I have two problems:

- The way to make useful is ugly and slow because I need to transform the objects type list, dict (and any other) into a string and later evaluate it, returned it again into list, dict, etc.
- The last part of the code `if __name__ == '__main__':` need still using the evil function `eval()` because it does not work with `ast.literal_eval()`.

These are my two problems. If someone can help me solving these two I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()` here (nor is it a problem here as you are *already able to execute code* from the command line).

Python allows you to use expressions on the command line:

```
python -c "import filePython; filePython.funct_3('str', ['listVar'], {'dictVar': 'foo'})"
```

The [`-c <command>` switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) is like `eval()` on steroids, in that it accepts full statements, not just expressions. Trying to avoid the problems of `eval()` here is simply not going to make any *difference* as arbitrary code execution is already going to happen.

Comment: It does not work for my scrips. One of them has `def distance(inFile, model='identity')`, where `inFile` could be a file and `model='identity'` is a method for make a matrix based on identity. When I try `python -c "from amarna import dendro; dendro.distance(allElasmoRNA, 'identity')" I get back `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'allElasmoRNA' is not defined`

Comment: @IvánCastro: you'd need to define `allElasmoRNA`, yes. Is it a filename? Then use `open()`: `python -c "from amarna import dendro; dendro.distance(open('allElasmoRNA'), 'identity')"`.

Comment: @IvánCastro: you need to provide **complete** Python code.

Comment: Sorry mate. It is a big code. In fact it is a module with 9 .py files and 1350 lines (150 lines per file).

Comment: @IvánCastro: from the command line, I mean, your code was not complete. If `allElasmoRNA` is a file object already opened elsewhere, you'd need to import that too. What would you do in the interactive interpreter to get this to run?